# Will a failed @import url() request block the rest of the CSS in the file from being applied

Tags: css, browser

If a CSS file that starts with a `@import url()` containing a link to a stylesheet hosted on a external server and the request to load that file fails, will the subsequent CSS rules in the rest of the file be applied?

For example:

```css
/* main-styles.css */

@import url("//external-url.com/styles.css")

h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Will the `<h1>` element be colored red?

Comment: you can't import css in your html like this..

Comment: This is contained within another css file not placed directly in the html

Comment: if this CSS part is accessible, it will be applied, it does not need @import to be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing in both Chrome and Firefox browsers it appears that having the `@import url()` request fail does *not* impact any styles contained in the rest of the CSS file from being applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your head section..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="external-url.com/styles.css">
```

instead of using import..

Comment: My question is if I don't set it as a separate link will the rest of the css load, not what my alternatives are.